# Flutter http post request to GitHub API

Tags: flutter, authentication, github

I am a new flutter developer working on my first project.
I have a GitHub repository which host a REST api. When i use http.get, everything works fine but when i try to write files using the post method to the api, It doesn't work. I have some authentication issues even if i use access tokens. I tried using client ID and client secret but it couldn't help. I need a step by step guide on how to go about it. I'm really confused at this point. I need your help. Thank you

```dart
  Future postData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api.github.com/repos/mypt-studio/papsapi/contents/user/detail.json');
    final content = '{"username":"testuser", "repname":"john Doe"}';

    final Map<String, String> body = {
      'message': 'first post',
      'content': content,
    };
    final response = await http.post(url,
        body: jsonEncode(body), headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $PAT'});
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
```

I tried using client ID and client secret but it couldn't help
The post request will be sent by the users in the app.

Comment: Have you tried also sending the `User-Agent` header?

Comment: No please, I don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the `User-Agent` header in your requests. As per the [GitHub REST API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/getting-started-with-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#user-agent):

> All API requests must include a valid `User-Agent` header. The `User-Agent` header identifies the user or application that is making the request.
>
> By default, GitHub CLI sends a valid `User-Agent` header. However, GitHub recommends using your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent` header value. This allows GitHub to contact you if there are problems.
>
> The following is an example `User-Agent` for an app named `Awesome-Octocat-App`:
>
> ```
> User-Agent: Awesome-Octocat-App
> ```
>
> Requests with no `User-Agent` header will be rejected. If you provide an invalid `User-Agent` header, you will receive a `403 Forbidden` response.

So you request call would look like this:

```dart
final response = await http.post(url,
  body: jsonEncode(body),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $PAT',
    'User-Agent': 'your_app.com',
  },
);
```

Where `your_app.com` is your application ID or any string that you would like to identify your calls as some API client.